# Entities in participate in the 0 related 'Role' were found. 1 'Role' is expected

Tags: c#, wpf, entities

I have 3 tables

```
Roles
------
RoleId(PK)
RoleName
RoleDescription

CustomPermissions
-----------------
PermissionId(PK)
PermissionName
PermissionDescription

RolePermissionMappings
------------------------
RoleId (PK)
PermissionId(PK)
Role_RoleId(FK)
CustomPermission_PermissionId(FK)
```

Idividually i am able to add values to Roles and CustomPermissions table.
While i am trying to map the values in RolePermissionMappings table i am getting this error.

```
Entities in 'RolePermissionMappingContainer.RolePermissionMappings' 
participate in the 'RoleRolePermissionMapping' relationship. 0 related 'Role' were found. 1 'Role' is expected.
```

Role has n number of permissions, they have to map as like this in RolePermissionMappings table

```
RoleId   PermissionId
------   ------------
  2          2
  2          4
  2          5
  2          8
  2          10
```

my code here

```
bool ICustomPermissions.AddPermissionsToRole(RoleDataContract role, List<PermissionDataContract> permissions)
{
    using(_context = new RolePermissionMappingContainer())
    {
        RolePermissionMapping rpm = new RolePermissionMapping();
        {
            rpm.RoleId =  role.RoleId;

            foreach (PermissionDataContract pdc in permissions)
            {
                rpm.PermissionId =  pdc.PermissionId;
                //_context.RolePermissionMappings.AddObject(rpm);
                _context.RolePermissionMappings.AddObject(rpm);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Please correct me where im getting in to the error.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new instance of `RolePermissionMapping` for each `PermissionDataContract` in `permissions`:

```
bool ICustomPermissions.AddPermissionsToRole(RoleDataContract role, List<PermissionDataContract> permissions)
    {
       using(_context = new RolePermissionMappingContainer())
       {

               foreach (PermissionDataContract pdc in permissions)
               {

                   RolePermissionMapping rpm = new RolePermissionMapping()
                   {
                       RoleId = role.RoleId,
                       PermissoinId = pdc.PermissionId
                   }

                   _context.RolePermissionMappings.AddObject(rpm);
                   _context.SaveChanges();
               }
       }
       return true;
    }
```